# Нужен эквивалент кода ванильного JS на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Пишу кастомный селектор. Нужен именно не дефолтный. Нужно, чтобы в каждом селекте был текст первого опшина. на Javascript уже давно сделал. как переписать код на jQuery? перепробовал уже и `parent()` и `next()` и `first()` в разных взаимодействиях. Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, либо в какую сторону смотреть

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.category-select-block').forEach (item => {
     item.innerHTML = item.closest('.category-select').querySelector('.category-option').innerHTML;
});
```

```css
.category-select {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}
.category-select-block {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-select">
    <div class="category-select-block"></div>
    <div class="category-option">Ukraine sport</div>
    <div class="category-option">Canada sport</div>
    <div class="category-option">USA sport</div>
    <div class="category-option">Germany sport</div>
</div>
<div class="category-select">
    <div class="category-select-block"></div>
    <div class="category-option">Small</div>
    <div class="category-option">Medium</div>
    <div class="category-option">Big</div>
</div>
<div class="category-select">
    <div class="category-select-block"></div>
    <div class="category-option">Price</div>
    <div class="category-option">Quantity</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.category-select-block').each(function() {
  $(this).html(
    $(this).closest('.category-select').find('.category-option').eq(0).html()
  );
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @VasylBakanovskyi На здоровье. Успехов!